# registered user in joomla is not approved in CB component

Tags: php, joomla2.5, joomla-community-builder

I use default joomla 2.5 user registration(login form module's create account link).After registration confirmed by user, the user appears as not approved/confirmed in community builder user list(CB component "user management" tab), but the user is approved in joomla user manager.Is not it automatic that when registered through joomla, the user is also confirmed/approved as CB user??

I searched through google and following things i confirmed but still not working -

```
1.In CB field management enabled only name,username,email fields under "Registration?" column
2.User-Joomla! and Authentication-Joomla plugins are enabled
```

what to do next to solve the problem and get solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would suggest to ask this question on CB forum as the forum is very active but i think its paid, i'm not sure.
One more thing you can do is write a joomla user plugin. There are many Joomla user events & use correct one like onAfterUserCreate. Check CB tables & Add your code which approved CB users in your user plugin. You don't need to hack any core files of Joomla or CB.
I hope this is useful to you. Thank You.

Comment: That was also the last thing in my mind.If any expert can point me to any other solutions or existing plugins.